# Can I define a __repr__ for a class rather than an instance?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, metaclass

Can I define a `__repr__` for a class rather than an instance? For example, I'm trying to do this

```
class A(object):
    @classmethod
    def __repr__(cls):
        return 'My class %s' % cls
```

What I get is

```
In [58]: a=A()

In [59]: a
Out[59]: My class <class '__main__.A'>

In [60]: A
Out[60]: __main__.A
```

I'm trying to get the output of line 60 to look like "My Class A", not for the instance a. The reason I want to do this is I'm generating a lot of classes using Python's metaclass. And I want a more readable way to identify the class than the stock repr.

Comment: Misunderstood your problem. Posted another (hopefully correct) answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to define `__repr__` on the metaclass.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __repr__(cls):
        return 'My class %s' % cls.__name__

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
```

`__repr__` returns a representation of an instance of an object. So by defining `__repr__` on `A`, you're specifying what you want `repr(A())` to look like.

To define the representation of the class, you need to define how an instance of `type` is represented. In this case, replace `type` with a custom metaclass with `__repr__` defined as you need.

```
>> repr(A)
My class A
```

If you want to define a custom `__repr__` for each class, I'm not sure there's a particularly clean way to do it. But you could do something like this.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __repr__(cls):
        if hasattr(cls, '_class_repr'):
            return getattr(cls, '_class_repr')()
        else:
            return super(Meta, cls).__repr__()

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    @classmethod
    def _class_repr(cls):
        return 'My class %s' % cls.__name__

class B(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
```

Then you can customize on a per-class basis.

```
>> repr(A)
My class A
>> repr(B)
<__main__.B object at 0xb772068c>
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3 `__metaclass__` has no special meaning, instead you should use `class A(metaclass=Meta)`.

Comment: @RobWouters Thanks :) Didn't realize that had changed.

Comment: Thank you. That make sense. One issue is iPython seems to do its own thing rather than using repr in its REPL :(

Comment: I am withdrawing my erroneous answer (redefining \_\_builtins\_\_.repr as non-working) and vote for this one instead. Thanks jsbueno for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

> **Can I define a __repr__ for a class rather than an instance?**

Sure, I demonstrate here, with a `__repr__` that passes the `repr` test.

```
class Type(type):
    def __repr__(cls):
        """
        >>> Type('Baz', (Foo, Bar,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None})
        Type('Baz', (Foo, Bar,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None})
        """
        name = cls.__name__
        parents = ', '.join(b.__name__ for b in cls.__bases__)
        if parents:
            parents += ','
        namespace = ', '.join(': '.join(
          (repr(k), repr(v) if not isinstance(v, type) else v.__name__)) 
               for k, v in cls.__dict__.items())
        return 'Type(\'{0}\', ({1}), {{{2}}})'.format(name, parents, namespace)

    def __eq__(cls, other):
        return (cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, cls.__dict__) == (
                other.__name__, other.__bases__, other.__dict__)
```

And to demonstrate:

```
class Foo(object): pass

class Bar(object): pass
```

Either Python 2:

```
class Baz(Foo, Bar): 
    __metaclass__ = Type
```

Or Python 3:

```
class Baz(Foo, Bar, metaclass=Type): 
    pass
```

Or fairly universally:

```
Baz = Type('Baz', (Foo, Bar), {})
>>> Baz
Type('Baz', (Foo, Bar,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None})
```

And to do the `repr` test:

```
def main():
    print Baz
    assert Baz == eval(repr(Baz))
```

What is the `repr` test? It's the above test from the documentation on `repr`:

```
>>> help(repr)
Help on built-in function repr in module __builtin__:

repr(...)
    repr(object) -> string

    Return the canonical string representation of the object.
    For most object types, eval(repr(object)) == object.
```